# creating bucket if it doesn't exists already

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I want to check if a specific bucket exists, if not create new one.

I need to know how can I detect in if the bucket already exists using aws.phar + php

Here is the pseudo code

```
$bucket = 'my-bucket';

//some code to detect if bucket name 'my-bucket' exists *suggest here*
//$myBucketExists = $client->someMethode()

if(!$myBucketExists){

      $result = $client->createBucket(array(
         'Bucket' => $bucket
      ));

      // Wait until the bucket is created
      $client->waitUntil('BucketExists', array('Bucket' => $bucket));
}
// rest of the code using the bucket
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [headBucket()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_headBucket)

```
$myBucketExists = $client->headBucket( array('Bucket' => $bucket) );
```

Comment: There is also a [doesBucketExists()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_doesBucketExist) helper method which uses headBucket.

Comment: with headBucket() method I have to write my code of creating new bucket in catch block as headBucket will throw an exception if bucket doen't exists. This way it works. Thanks @Nadh

Comment: doesBucketExist() works awesome. Even both methods works fine I'll prefer doesBucketExist() as best coding practise. Thank you @Jeremy Lindblom

Comment: When I'm using 
  $client->doesBucketExist($bucket); 
it returns false, even if bucket exists. Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The following example sets $myBucketExists to true if the bucket with the name $bucket exists and you have access to the bucket. whereas doesBucketExist method just checks if a bucket exists in that name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$s3 = $this->awsService->get('S3');

if(!$s3->doesBucketExist($bucket)) {
    $s3->createBucket(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket
    ));
}
```

Comment: I think it's worth noting that doesBucketExist will return true if the bucket exists in ANY S3 account, not just the one you are currently using. I think passing false as the second parameter will 
prevent 403 responses causing this function to return true.

See the documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html